applying different layers to different services in one tonic server
I have two versions of a layer, EndpointTimer_1 and EndpointTimer_2 which track slightly different metrics. I want EndpointTimer_1 to be applied to Server_1 and EndpointTimer_2 to applied to Server_2.
What's the correct way to use a common ServerBuilder object to facilitate this? Currently I have something like
use tonic::transport::Server;

let mut server_builder = Server::builder()
    .layer(EndpointTimerLayer::new())
    .layer(ConcurrencyGaugeLayer::new());

let provider_1 = provider_1_impl::new(&CONFIG)?;
let provider_2 = provider_2_impl::new(&CONFIG)?;
let router = server_builder
    .add_service(Server_1::new(provider_1))
    .add_service(Server_2::new(provider_2));
router.serve(addr).await?;

and I want something like
use tonic::transport::Server;

let mut server_builder = Server::builder()
    .layer(ConcurrencyGauge::new());

let provider_1 = provider_1_impl::new(&CONFIG)?;
let provider_2 = provider_2_impl::new(&CONFIG)?;
let router = server_builder
    .add_service(Server_1::new(provider_1).layer(EndpointTimerLayer_1::new())
    .add_service(Server_2::new(provider_2).layer(EndpointTimerLayer_2::new());
router.serve(addr).await?;

but I can't figure out the right way to make it work.

Took a bunch of experimenting and reading through tonic source code, and I still have some things I don't understand, but the functional answer is to first, implement the NamedService trait for each layer:
use tonic::transport::server::NamedService;

impl<T> NamedService for EndpointTimer_1<T>
where
    T: NamedService,
{
    const NAME: &'static str = T::NAME;
}

Note, that the error type for the layer's service must be Infallible, e.g.
use std::convert::Infallible;

impl<T, RequestBody, ResponseBody> Service<tonic::codegen::http::Request<RequestBody>>
    for EndpointTimer_1<T>
where
    T: Service<
            tonic::codegen::http::Request<RequestBody>,
            Response = tonic::codegen::http::Response<ResponseBody>,
            Error = Infallible,
        > + Send,

instead of the example-provided type Error = Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>;. AFAICT this works because the protobuf-generated server is Infallible as well? Unsure, would appreciate an explanation of this by anyone in the know.
Finally, services can be registered by wrapping them in layers individually:
let mut server_builder = Server::builder()
    .layer(ConcurrencyGauge::new());

let provider_1 = provider_1_impl::new(&CONFIG)?;
let server_1 = Server_1::new(provider_1);

let provider_2 = provider_2_impl::new(&CONFIG)?;
let server_2 = Server_2::new(provider_2);


let router = server_builder
    .add_service(EndpointTimer_1::new(Server_1))
    .add_service(EndpointTimer_2::new(Server_2));
router.serve(addr).await?;

Note that this is using the Timer itself, which takes a Service as an argument to new(), and not the Layer around it.
